# Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError Verifier rejected class due to bad method DataBinderMapperImpl.internalGetViewDataBinding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I'm getting this error on Android 5x but i don't know what it could be the problem. I'm getting the error on the file FragmentDataNewjourneyBindingImpl. So i tracked and the file that is using the FragmentDataNewJourneyBinding is AuthenticationFragment. So it could be either my xml has something wrong or my fragment has.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="br.com.gabriel.novajornada.security.auth.AuthenticationViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="constantes"
        type="br.com.gabriel.novajornada.constants.ConstantsKt" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    style="@style/bo_texto_regular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                    android:text="@string/fill_data_title_new_journey"
                    android:textColor="#1a1b1a"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout11" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView98"
                    style="@style/bo_texto_regular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text="@string/fill_data_subtitle"
                    android:textColor="#4a4b4a"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

                <br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_cpf"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    android:hint="@string/identifier_field_title"
                    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme.ClearButton"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyProfile.Error"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView98">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/identifier"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextTheme"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:text="@={viewModel.credentials.cpf}"
                        app:mask="@{ `###.###.###-##` }" />
                </br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout>

                <br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    android:hint="@string/name_field"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme.ClearButton"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyProfile.Error"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_cpf">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextTheme"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ âãàáäêèéëîìíïôòóõöùúüñçÂÃÀÁÄÊÈÉËÎÌÍÏÔÒÓÕÖÙÚÜÑÇ"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                        android:maxLength="@{constantes.NAMES_MAX_LENGTH}"
                        android:text="@={viewModel.credentials.name}" />

                </br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout>

                <br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:hint="@string/cellphone_ddd_field_title"
                    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme.ClearButton"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyProfile.Error"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_name">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextTheme"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:text="@={viewModel.credentials.phoneNumber}"
                        app:mask="@{ `(##) #####-####` }" />

                </br.com.original.common.components.BOTextInputLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnConfirm"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_phone"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/politicas"
                        style="@style/seja_subtitle_h3_regular"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin"
                        android:text="@string/politicas_header_new_journey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openPoliticas"
                        style="@style/seja_subtitle_h3_regular"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin"
                        android:paddingTop="2pt"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin"
                        android:text="@string/privacy_policy_new_journey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/politicas" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
                    style="@style/seja_button_bordeless"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_seja"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                    android:enabled="@{identifier.text.length() == 14 &amp;&amp; phone.text.length() == 15 &amp;&amp; name.text.length() > 2}"
                    android:text="@string/continue_button"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/seja_bar_layout_newjourney_center" />

    <br.com.original.bank.novajornada.common.component.BOStateView
        android:id="@+id/stateView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:msv_errorView="@layout/seja_error_view_newjourney"
        app:msv_loadingView="@layout/seja_loading_view_newjourney" />

</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

This is AuthenticationFragment.kt. I put only the part of the bindingView declaration because i think it's more important:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class AuthenticationFragment : NavigationFragment() {

    val viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel by viewModel()
    lateinit var bindingView: FragmentDataNewjourneyBinding
    lateinit var formValidate: FormValidate
    private val novaJornadaActivity: NovaJornadaActivity by lazy { activity as NovaJornadaActivity }
    private val management: TagManagement by inject()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        bindingView = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentDataNewjourneyBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_data_newjourney, container, false)
                .apply {
                    lifecycleOwner = this@AuthenticationFragment
                    viewModel = this@AuthenticationFragment.viewModel
                }

        viewModel.checkUserPromoted((activity as NovaJornadaActivity).userPromoted)

        return bindingView.root
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation? I will be glad for anyone for trying to help me